# mongoose multiple population in a query and if one failed is there a way to get the rest of the populated data

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When i am writing a query to get a document with multiple population. 
one population id is empty, hence the entire query is throwing an error.

is there a way to get the data ignoring the missing population id?